# Custom activity - Push notification from marketing cloud to a app written in flutter

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, custom-activity, push-notification

**Goal:**: What I want is for my marketing team to be able to set up a geofence and a push-message through a custom activity in journey builder.

**Problem**: The mobilePUSH SDK doesn't support flutter which is what the app team has used to develop our mobile app.

I'm wondering how this would be implemented on a technical level from the SFMC side? What would needed to be sent from the custom activity/SFMC to the app team? Is there any good documentation on implementing this kind of solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are `Cordova` and `ReactNative` plugins for the Marketing Cloud Push SDK.  (ref. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/mobile-push-sdk.html) Those can be used as guides if you wish to create a bridge for Flutter.